# React-Native web app on apache Routing issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, expo, react-native-web

I'm coding an app with React Native for web. The app will be on an Apache2 server and will be a simple 'messenger'.

For now I'm just trying to create links between pages with url modification.

When I load the page on my apache server, the login page is perfectly displayed. When I'm clicking on a the login button, the url is modified from (https://domain.name/login to https://domain.name/home).
The problem is that the server understands the '**/home**' as a folder. And then the app is not working as espected like in local on the 19006 port.

I tried to find some person with the same problem, but I can't find anything close to my situation (Unless I'm mistaken).

I also tried to redirect all the link with an .htaccess to the index.html to correct the problem but then the loading link (https://domain.name/login) is not callable and my app stay stuck on the App.js which is a black page :/

I think that something with the .htaccess can be done but I'm not sure about it.

Can someone try to find how to fix that link issue so that my app can work ?
I drop you the important of the code and thank you for your help :)

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={() => {
              
                return(
                  this.state.isUserAuthenticated ?
                      <Redirect to="/home" /> :
                      <Redirect to="/login" /> 
                )
            }}
          />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
        </View>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

**login.js**

```
class Login extends React.Component {

    logIn = () => {
        this.goToHome();
    }

    goToSignup() {
        window.location.replace('/signup');
    }

    goToHome() {
        window.location.replace('/home');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.main}>

                        <View style={styles.buttonBox}>
                            <Button title='Log in' onPress={this.logIn} />
                        </View>

                        <View style={styles.buttonBox}>
                            <Button title='Sign Up' onPress={this.goToSignup} />
                        </View>



            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**GIF showing the expected functionalism**

[How it looks when I'm developping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N07Y3.gif)

*The original link is* **/login** *and goes to* **/signup** *after clicking on Signup.*

Comment: I found something digusting to make it works.
Creating folders **home**, **login** and **signup** and adding the same index.html in each folder.
I have now 4 times my index.html
I hope someone can help me to find a better solution :/